# Cannot change GTK and icon after changing LightDM greeter

Tags: themes, lightdm, gtk

I changed my LightDM greeter and suddenly I cannot change my gtk or icon theme. The dconf settings are there, but the system is not responding to changes, nor are the themes being used by all applications. GTK+ 2.x applications are using the default/fallback theme.

What gives?

#### Update:

I thought the permissions on some folder might be the problem, but I was wrong. Even after making sure everything in my home folder is assigned to my username and has the right permissions I still have the issue. Changing to SDDM allowed me to at least change the window manager theme but I still can't change anything else. It says the theme is set to my choice in dconf editor but it isn't actually being set otherwise.

I tried lxappearance, but it is only affecting GTK2 applications. GTK3 applications are still stuck with the default theme and I can't get them to change at all.

#### Another clue:

GTK 2 applications run as root are not using the theme I selected in lxappearance.

Comment: I do not know if my situation is similar but I cannot change themes on Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS 64-bit when I change the GTK, window or icon theme they are either corrupted or nothing changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to delete `~/.config/dconf/user` while logged out (in other words, from a virtual terminal) to get my settings back to working order. It's not a perfect fix, and it meant that some other things got reset of course, but it was the only way to get dconf to reset without restoring on log out.

See [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-2215394.html).